# Need Outlook Attachments File Names ( or only extensions ) counts exported for selected emails into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I wish to extract the filenames of the attachments I have received into the public folder and extract ( paste ) them into the excel file for easy analysis.

I have the below code however it is only selecting details of 1 email.

I wish to understand where it does wrong.

```
    Option Explicit
     Sub CopyToExcel()
     Dim xlApp As Object
     Dim xlWB As Object
     Dim xlSheet As Object
     Dim rCount As Long
     Dim bXStarted As Boolean
     Dim enviro As String
     Dim strPath As String

     Dim currentExplorer As Explorer
     Dim Selection As Selection
     Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
     Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
     Dim j As Long
     Dim i As Integer
     Dim Report As String
     Dim attachment As attachment
     Dim obj As Object
     Dim strColB, strColC, strColD, strColE, strColF As String

    ' Get Excel set up
    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    'the path of the workbook
     strPath = enviro & "\Documents\test.xlsx"
         On Error Resume Next
         Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
         If Err <> 0 Then
             Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
             Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
             bXStarted = True
         End If
         On Error GoTo 0
         'Open the workbook to input the data
         Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
         Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
        ' Process the message record

        On Error Resume Next
    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
    rCount = xlSheet.Range("B" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row


    ' get the values from outlook
    Set currentExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set Selection = currentExplorer.Selection
      For Each obj In Selection

        Set olItem = obj
        Set myAttachments = olItem.Attachments

     'collect the fields
    Next


    For Each Selection In Selection
        If Selection.Class = olMail Then

    End If

    For Each attachment In olItem.Attachments
        Report = strColC & GetAttachmentInfo(attachment)
        strColB = olItem.Attachments.Count
        strColD = olItem.SenderEmailAddress
        strColE = olItem.Categories
        strColF = olItem.ReceivedTime



    'write them in the excel sheet

      xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = strColB
      xlSheet.Range("c" & rCount) = Report
      xlSheet.Range("d" & rCount) = strColD
      xlSheet.Range("e" & rCount) = strColE
      xlSheet.Range("f" & rCount) = strColF

    'Next row
      rCount = rCount + 1
    Next


    Next

         xlWB.Close 1
         If bXStarted Then
             xlApp.Quit
         End If

         Set olItem = Nothing
         Set obj = Nothing
         Set currentExplorer = Nothing
         Set xlApp = Nothing
         Set xlWB = Nothing
         Set xlSheet = Nothing


     End Sub

    Public Function GetAttachmentInfo(attachment As attachment)
        On Error GoTo On_Error
        Dim Report
        Dim strColA, strColB, strColC, strColD, strColE, strColF As String


        GetAttachmentInfo = ""

        Report = strColA & "Display Name: " & attachment.DisplayName
        Report = strColC & "File Name: " & attachment.filename

        GetAttachmentInfo = Report

        Exiting:
            Exit Function

        On_Error:
        MsgBox "error=" & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
        Resume Exiting

    End Function
```

Comment: (1) You would find it a lot easier to debug your macros if you indented consistently.  (2) It appears to me that the loop that outputs the attachments of myAttachments is not within the loop that sets myAttachments. You need to move the `For Each attachment In olItem.Attachments` to below `Set myAttachments = olItem.Attachments`. (3) You do not check an item has attachments before accessing those attachments.  I would expect this code to fail if `olItem.Attachments.Count = 0`.

Comment: Hi Tony, you are fabulous Sir!, I know I can debug and resolve many things , issue is the lack of time, I'm from operations and have to manage many operational activities as well. I'm trying to make things easier hence trying out vba macros. thank you for being so patient and answering the queries.  I am running into trouble again,  I made the changes as requested, however I only get 1 file name which is the top most file in the list of attachments if the email has more than 1 attachment, how can this code fetch more than 1 file name ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to Outlook at the moment so the following is from studying the macro rather than trying to run it.

---

`Public Function GetAttachmentInfo(attachment As attachment)`
You need `As String` at the end if you want a value returned.  You are using `attachment` both as a keyword and as the name of a parameter.  Please rename the parameter.

---

```
Report = strColA & "Display Name: " & attachment.DisplayName
Report = strColC & "File Name: " & attachment.filename
```

`strColA` and `strColA` have be declared with a `Dim` statement but have not been given values so are blank.  The second statement overwrites the value of `Report` set by the first.

---

I see examples of your use of `On Error` repeatedly.  I did the same until I realised it was totally unhelpful.  During development, you want the interpreter to stop on the statement giving the error so you know what to correct.  In a production macro, released to non-technical users, you need something more friendly.  I suggest you delete this code.

---

I cannot see why you are getting the name of the first attachment but not the other attachments.  I suggest you correct these errors and then repost your revised code.